# Post-Receive Hook Does Not Error But Does Not Copy Files

Tags: git, git-post-receive

I am attempting to use git to deploy changes to a site on a locally hosted server. When I push the changes from my local directory to the dev server, the post-receive hook provides the feedback I would expect if it were working, but it doesn't actually change any files in the working tree.

Also, I am developing on a mac and the site is hosted on a windows server shared on the network and mounted to /Volumes/I$

Here is the hook script

```
#!/bin/bash

GIT_DIR=/Volumes/I$/intranet_dev
WORK_TREE=/Volumes/I$/intranetdev

while read oldrev newrev ref
do
    if [[ $ref =~ .*/master$ ]];
    then
        echo "Master ref received.  Deploying master branch to test server..."
        mkdir -p $WORK_TREE
        git --work-tree=$WORK_TREE --git-dir=$GIT_DIR checkout -f
        echo "Git hooks deploy complete"
    else
        echo "Ref $ref successfully received.  Doing nothing: only the master branch may be deployed on this server."
    fi
done
```

The bare repository is located at a remote which I have labeled "test". When I issue the following command, I get the following output in my terminal...

```
computername:intranet username$ git push test master
Counting objects: 6, done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (6/6), done.
Writing objects: 100% (6/6), 566 bytes | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 6 (delta 5), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Master ref received.  Deploying master branch to test server...
remote: Git hooks deploy complete
To /Volumes/I$/intranet_dev
   1d9eb1f..f49b533  master -> master
```

This all looks as it should, but the changed files are not copied over.

Comment: You're checking out the current HEAD.  You sure that's attached to the `master` branch?  Why rely on that?  Try checking out `master`.  Minor point: `if [[ $ref = *master ]]` is all you need,

Comment: I will try that out. This script is based on one I got from digital ocean a while back, so I just used what they suggested. Sounds like good advice, though.

Comment: That did the trick! Post it as an answer, and I will mark it as correct.

Comment: I'd also recommend checking explicitly for `$ref = refs/heads/master`. Otherwise you'll deploy master when someone pushes to a branch or tag named `not-the-master`, for instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're checking out the current `HEAD`.  You sure that's attached to the master branch? Why rely on that? Try checking out `master` instead.

Minor point, `if [[ $ref = */master ]]` (or as long as we're being safe and all, `if [[ $ref = refs/heads/master ]]` as @torek points out) is all you need there.